# Why are @expo/vector-icons undefined when mocking expo with jest.mock?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, expo

For unit testing test w/ jest i had mocked the expo directory with the following:

```
jest.mock('expo', () => {
  const { View } = require('react-native');
  const constantsMock = { // the camera class has constants defined on it
    Type: {
      back: 'BACK',
      front: 'FRONT',
    },
  };
  const cameraMock = Object.assign({}, View, { Constants: constantsMock }); // assign so we can modify a copy, not the orig View - since its passed by reference

  return {
    Permissions: {
      askAsync: jest.fn(),
    },
    Camera: cameraMock,
    CameraObject: View,
  };
});
```

which worked - but lead to the following error being logged by react:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

    Check the render method of `InKeyboardCamera`.
        in InKeyboardCamera
```

Through process of elimination (i.e., taking out parts of the rendered component and checking when it was being thrown and when it was not) i tracked down that the component which produced this error was the following:

```
(<SimpleLineIcons name="refresh" size={19} color="white" />)
```

which was imported with this statement:

```
import { SimpleLineIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

That was strange, because i had not mocked the `@expo/vector-icons` module and it was working live but not in the test environment. But sure enough, logging out `console.log(SimpleLineIcons)` in that file resulted in `undefined`.

I was able to eliminate the error with this:

```
jest.mock('@expo/vector-icons', () => {
  const { View } = require('react-native');
  return {
    SimpleLineIcons: View,
    Ionicons: View,
  };
});
```

but it leaves the question: why would mocking the `expo` package affect the `@expo/vector-icons` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Expo` basically has an '`expo-vector-icons`' module built in from SDK32. This is why '`expo-vector-icons`' modules do not need to be installed separately when creating projects through `Expo`, and installing them separately can cause conflicts.

It is understandable by looking at the pattern of the conversion that is ignored in the `preset` file.

[expo/packages/jest-expo/jest-preset.js](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/jest-expo/jest-preset.js)

```js
jestPreset.transformIgnorePatterns = [
  'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)',
];
```